# Trying to install a headless xbmc to Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, server, xbmc, virtualization

I was trying to follow this [guide](http://cyanlabs.net/tutorials/guide-headless-xbmc-server-for-linux). I have a vm running Ubuntu 12.04 and it currently houses Sab+, Nzbdrone, CouchPotato and MariaDB. I'm trying to install a headless XBMC so it will be running 24x7 and constantly updated and I do not have to run the update library command from one of the other computers or clients hosting xbmc.
So I tried running the following commands

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y && sudo reboot
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:team-xbmc/unstable
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:team-xbmc/xbmc-ppa-build-depends
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get build-dep xbmc
```

and that is where I find a problem. This is the result from the last line.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libglew1.6-dev' instead of 'libglew-dev'
Note, selecting 'libsamplerate0-dev' instead of 'libsamplerate-dev'
The following packages have unmet dependencies: libmysqlclient-dev : Depends: libmysqlclient18 (= 5.5.37-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) but 10.0.11+maria-1~precise is to be installed
E: Build-dependencies for xbmc could not be satisfied.
```

Any ideas on how to proceed?